# Optimise SQL query: find items that are geographically touching, but without association

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very specific problem, I am not entirely sure if this is the right place to ask this question. From our client we get data submitted to us, and to verify the quality of that data, we run a set of queries to check the consistency of the data.

In our data-model, we have routes (lines) and structures (points), and when a structure is positioned on a route, there should be link present (in another table). To verify this, I run the following query:

```
      select s.id as id, r.id as unconnected_route_id
      from structure s, route r
      WHERE s.batch_number = '%{batch_number}'
        and r.batch_number = '%{batch_number}'
        and SDO_ANYINTERACT(s.geometry, r.geometry) = 'TRUE'
        and not exists (
          select * from feature_connectivity
          where feature_id = r.id and feature_code=1001
            and node1_feature_code = 1003
            and (node1_id = s.id or node2_id = s.id)
        )
```

This worked fine in testing phase, but now we are comparing a set of ~25000 structures versus a set of ~25000 routes and it takes literally hours. All indexes are in place, I checked with our dba how we could improve this, but we were unable to come up with something.

[UPDATE: add explain plan, and datamodel/indexes]

Datamodel:

- ROUTE and STRUCTURE both have an ID, BATCH_NUMBER, GEOMETRY field (and a bunch of other irrelevant columns)
- both tables have an index on batch-number and a spatial index on geometry

The indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX "INFRA"."ROUTE_IX01" ON "INFRA"."ROUTE" ("BATCH_NUMBER") 
CREATE INDEX "INFRA"."ROUTE_SX01" ON "INFRA"."ROUTE" ("GEOMETRY") INDEXTYPE IS "MDSYS"."SPATIAL_INDEX"  PARAMETERS ('layer_gtype=curve');

CREATE INDEX "INFRA"."STRUCTURE_IX01" ON "INFRA"."STRUCTURE" ("BATCH_NUMBER") 
CREATE INDEX "INFRA"."STRUCTURE_SX01" ON "INFRA"."STRUCTURE" ("GEOMETRY") INDEXTYPE IS "MDSYS"."SPATIAL_INDEX"  PARAMETERS ('layer_gtype=point');
```

The FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY is a bit different:

```
FEATURE_ID, FEATURE_CODE, NODE1_ID, NODE1_FEATURE_CODE, NODE2_ID, NODE2_FEATURE_CODE
```

with the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX "COMMON"."FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY_IX01" ON "COMMON"."FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY ("FEATURE_ID", "FEATURE_CODE") 
CREATE INDEX "COMMON"."FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY_IX02" ON "COMMON"."FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY ("NODE1_ID", "NODE1_FEATURE_CODE") 
CREATE INDEX "COMMON"."FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY_IX03" ON "COMMON"."FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY ("NODE2_ID", "NODE2_FEATURE_CODE") 
CREATE INDEX "COMMON"."FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY_IX04" ON "COMMON"."FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY" ("BATCH_NUMBER") 
create unique index FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY_IX05 on FEATURE_CONNECTIVITY (FEATURE_ID, FEATURE_CODE, NODE1_ID, NODE1_FEATURE_CODE, NODE2_ID, NODE2_FEATURE_CODE)
```

The explain plan for the query is as follows:

[image]

Does any body have any suggestions how we can improve this?

Comment: Try to create `SDO_ANYINTERACT` as a table instead a function. Then join structure and route to this table can be efficient.

Comment: @Franek SDO_ANYINTERACT is a standard Oracle Spatial operator, see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10826/sdo_operat.htm#BGEJHDGD).

Comment: In that case - there was no question ;). Thanks for indulgent response relative to my proposal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so good at reading explain plans, but one of the comments I had (on dba.stackexchange.com --where I had to delete the question, because apparently you are not allowed to post on both sites), is that the spatial index was not used optimally.

#### First attempt: add a bounding box

In devising ways to split up the work, I thought to split up the query in 4 quadrants using the bounding box, and so I calculated the bounding box, and first attempted to just add the bounding box and that did wonders on my explain plan. So my query looked as follows:

```
select s.id as id, r.id as unconnected_route_id
  from structure s, route r
  WHERE s.batch_number = '202'
    and r.batch_number = '202'
    and SDO_ANYINTERACT(s.geometry, r.geometry) = 'TRUE'
    and SDO_INSIDE(r.geometry,
        SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 31370, NULL,
          SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),
          SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(161481.2819, 204758.7507, 181858.4903, 230979.198 ))
        ) = 'TRUE'
    and not exists (
      select * from feature_connectivity
      where feature_id = r.id and feature_code=1001
        and node1_feature_code = 1003
        and (node1_id = s.id or node2_id = s.id)
    )
```

and then my total cost of the explain plan dropped to 14081 :

[image]

This was already amazing, and the bounding box was large enough to contain everything, so I was a bit baffled Oracle itself did not handle it correctly. And furthermore: it would allow me to split the query later into quadrants if I wanted/needed.

#### Second attempt: use SDO_JOIN

But then our dba had a bright idea: use SDO_JOIN to build a temporary table. I already used this approach to look for doubles, but frankly without really understanding it. Secondly he used `minus` instead of the `not exists`.

So the query he suggested was:

```
        select r.id              route_id
        ,      s.id              struct_id
        from   route     r
        ,      structure s
        ,      table(sdo_join('route','geometry','structure','geometry','mask=ANYINTERACT')) j
        where  r.rowid = j.rowid1
        and    s.rowid = j.rowid2
        and    r.batch_number = s.batch_number
        and    r.batch_number = '202'
        minus
        ( select feature_id
          ,      node1_id
          from   common.feature_connectivity
          where  batch_number = '202'
          union all
          select feature_id
          ,      node2_id
          from   common.feature_connectivity
          where  batch_number = '202')
      ) results
      where results.struct_id = s.id and results.route_id = r.id
```

The weird thing is that the explain plan is 3 times worse than the original, but the execution speed is fenomenal :) Soooooo weird: do not trust explain plan?

The explain plan looks like:

[image]

This last query is the query we ended up using now, and the execution time has dropped from +24h to less then a minute.

Comment: Oh, I commented above and did not see your own answer, sorry :) But my suggestions were right - the problem was in the indexes. Now full scans are fast, but if your data will grow much bigger than you have now, you would probably need to use indexes. Tom Kyte's "Expert Oracle Database Architecture" book may give you lots of answers. And sorry for the delay again!

Comment: Mmmm maybe a good tip about the indexes. I did not get it first, but the last query does not use indexes anymore. The SDO_JOIN does all the work of course, I am guessing. My local database (on my development machine) is a lot quicker than the server of our client. So the +25h query takes 100secs on my machine.

Comment: And good tip to consider bitmap indexes too (had to do some reading to see/understand the relevance).

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing Oracle to use nested loops instead of hash joins like this:

```
select /*+ USE_NL(s r)*/s.id as id, r.id as unconnected_route_id
      from structure s, route r
      WHERE s.batch_number = '%{batch_number}'
        and r.batch_number = '%{batch_number}'
        and SDO_ANYINTERACT(s.geometry, r.geometry) = 'TRUE'
        and not exists (
          select /*+ NL_AJ(feature_connectivity)*/ * from feature_connectivity
          where feature_id = r.id and feature_code=1001
            and node1_feature_code = 1003
            and (node1_id = s.id or node2_id = s.id)
        )
```

Hash joins can be really slow when server does not have enough space in buffer. In that case it will write data to disc and then read it, and file read-writes are always slow.
If this would not work, please provide the structure of your tables, it may be helpful.

Comment: Wow, awesome, on a small test-set this improves the performance from 90secs to 15msec!!!! Now trying on the large set (which took 26hours ...)

Comment: @nathanvda It might been Oracle cache :) If you run the query first time, it caches the results, when you run the query second time it does not calculate it the second time, but takes the already calculated results from cache. Please share the results after you run it on larger set, I'm very curious if nested loops really helped. Thanks!

Comment: Aaaah bummer: the query is running for hours, and I cannot run "explain plan" myself on that database, so I had asked the dba. Apparently oracle already uses nested loops, the explain plan is identical for my original query and yours, so I am assuming it will not make a difference :(

Comment: Sorry! Would you please provide your tables structure?

Comment: Added + indexes. If you have more questions let me know.

Comment: Hi, @nathanvda ! Sorry, been too busy working and could not help you. Looking at the plan I would suggest that there's something wrong with your indexes. Just a thought: try dropping STRUCTURE_SX01 index and see what happens. And also, for ROUTE_IX01 and STRUCTURE_IX01 a BITMAP INDEX may be more suitable (I don't know your data, so I can not be sure about that). Also, please list your SPATIAL_INDEX index type.

Comment: Also "ROUTE and STRUCTURE both have an ID, BATCH_NUMBER, GEOMETRY" - those are NUMBER type, right?